# Oracle SQL develop. Foreign Key error : Unknown command

Tags: database, oracle11g, foreign-keys, oracle-sqldeveloper

Every time I try to do a Foreign Key I get error like this :

> Error starting at line 9 in command:
>       CONSTRAINT tp_landlordrole_FK FOREIGN KEY (useraccountid)
>       Error report:
>       Unknown Command

One Suggestion I got was to

```
ALTER TABLE 
ADD CONSTRAINT
```

The first table worked however when I tried the next table it didn't work the errors came back.

The following is an example of my code:

```
PROMPT 'Creating Table landlordrole'
CREATE TABLE tp_landlordrole
(
    landlordroleid          NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    useraccountid           NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    numberofpropertiesowned     Number(6),
CONSTRAINT tp_landlordrole_PK PRIMARY KEY ( landlordroleid ) ) ; 

ALTER TABLE tp_landlordrole
ADD CONSTRAINT tp_landlordrole_FK FOREIGN KEY (useraccountid)
REFERENCES  tp_useraccount(useraccountid) ON DELETE CASCADE ;

PROMPT Creating Index 'tp_landlordrole_I'
CREATE INDEX tp_landlordrole_I ON tp_landlordrole
( useraccountid );

PROMPT 'Creating Sequence tp_landlordroleid_seq for the tp_landlordrole table'
CREATE SEQUENCE tp_landlordroleid_seq START WITH 0 MINVALUE 0 NOCACHE;



PROMPT 'Creating Table realtorrole'
CREATE TABLE tp_realtorrole
(
    realtorroleid                   NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    useraccountid               NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    currentrealestatecompanyname    VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  tp_realtorrole_PK PRIMARY KEY ( realtorroleid ) ) ;

ALTER TABLE tp_realtorrole
ADD CONSTRAINT  tp_realtorrole_FK FOREIGN KEY ( useraccountid )
REFERENCES  tp_useraccount(useraccountid) );

PROMPT Creating Index 'tp_realtorrole_I'
CREATE INDEX tp_realtorrole_I ON tp_realtorrole
( useraccountid );

PROMPT 'Creating Sequence tp_realtorroleid_seq for the tp_realtorrole table'
CREATE SEQUENCE tp_realtorroleid_seq START WITH 0 MINVALUE 0 NOCACHE;
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You have `ADD ADD CONSTRAINT`.  That is not valid syntax.  Also, don't enclose identifier names (such as the index name) in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The code should look more like this:

```
PROMPT 'Creating Table landlordrole'
CREATE TABLE tp_landlordrole (
    landlordroleid          NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    useraccountid           NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    numberofpropertiesowned     Number(6),
    CONSTRAINT tp_landlordrole_PK PRIMARY KEY ( landlordroleid )
);

ALTER TABLE tp_landlordrole
    ADD CONSTRAINT tp_landlordrole_FK FOREIGN KEY (useraccountid)
        REFERENCES  tp_useraccount(useraccountid) ON DELETE CASCADE;

PROMPT 'Creating Index tp_landlordrole_I'
CREATE INDEX tp_landlordrole_I ON tp_landlordrole(useraccountid);

PROMPT 'Creating Sequence tp_landlordroleid_seq for the tp_landlordrole table'
CREATE SEQUENCE tp_landlordroleid_seq START WITH 0 MINVALUE 0 NOCACHE;

PROMPT 'Creating Table realtorrole'
CREATE TABLE tp_realtorrole (
    realtorroleid                   NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    useraccountid               NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    currentrealestatecompanyname    VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT  tp_realtorrole_PK PRIMARY KEY (realtorroleid)
);

ALTER TABLE tp_realtorrole
    ADD CONSTRAINT tp_realtorrole_FK FOREIGN KEY (useraccountid)
        REFERENCES tp_useraccount(useraccountid);
```

Of course, the foreign key references will fail, unless you have defined `tp_useraccount`.